# How to require client-side SSL certificate only for exern IPs in nginx server configuration?

Tags: nginx, ssl, redirect, https, reverse-proxy

I would like to configure nginx this way, that only extern page visitors (not 192.169.1.0/24) need to authenticate using client-side SSL certificates.

I already found, that extern and intern users can be distinguished by the geo module:

```
http {
  geo $isintern {
    default 0;
    192.169.1.0/24 1;
}
```

via: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811532/client-authentication-when-using-nginx-proxy-pass

How do I have to configure the server? I got to know, that one should try to circumvent if statements. Finally I would like to redirect people with access to an 403/401 error page.

```
upstream serverapp {
    server unix:/opt/a.socket;
}

server {
    listen        443;
    ssl on;
    server_name example.com;

    ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/certs/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/certs/server.key;
    ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/ca.crt;
    ssl_verify_client optional;

    if(!$isintern) {
        if($ssl_client_verify != SUCCESS) {
            return 403;
        }
    }

    error_page 403 401 /401.html

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://serverapp;
    }
}
```

The config above is not tested. How is it meant to be implemented?

Resources:

- http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#error_page
- http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule#if

Comment: - http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?10,214169
 - http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?29,173747

(also related)

Comment: What do you mean by _"How is it meant to be implemented?"_ You can use `return` and other directives of the `HttpRewriteModule` inside `if`.

Comment: 192.169.1.0/24 would also allow externs from IP range 192.169.1.* to connect without SSL. This is best solved with a packet filter blocking this range (not with nginx).

Answer (score -1):

You need two `server {}` blocks, one for external and one for internal access.  Nginx won't care if they point to the same root on the filesystem.  Ideally make a separate `.conf` file for each and put it in a directory `include`d by the main `nginx.conf` or other config file.

Each `server {}` block can have its own certificates, its own `server_name` directive for SNI to work properly, and you can limit access by IP of the internal site with `location / { allow IP/netmask; allow IP/netmask; deny all; }`

Comment: Have you tested this? I suspect it won't work as the two server {} blocks will conflict before the allow masks are even considered. I could be wrong of course.